# Cut String inside Quotation Mark

Tags: vb.net

I have this String:

"[" & vbCrLf & "  ""APPLE""" & vbCrLf & "]"

The only thing I need is APPLE.

I tried a few options with Split, Trim, Left and more, but they didn't work very well.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Why you have VB.NET code as string?

Comment: Is that the actual string that you have, or an expression that *creates* that string? I assume you may need [String.IndexOf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof) to get the positions of the quotes

Comment: Don't just provide a single example. Explain what the rules are that cover EVERY case. If you don't do that then you're forcing us to make assumptions and you should NEVER force us to make assumptions. If you can't describe the general case then you clearly haven't thought about the problem sufficiently to be asking the question in the first place.

Comment: @jmcilhinney is right, actually we could answer the question easily: `Dim apple = "APPLE"`. Finished, you have the apple.

Comment: `["“]+([^“"][\w\s*]+)[“"]+`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments above have said, there's not enough information to give an answer without making assumptions, which could be wrong.  I've assumed you want to extract the value between two quotation marks, regardless of what else is before or after.

If that's what you want, try this:

```
    Dim Result As String = Nothing
    Dim source As String = $"[{vbCrLf}""Apple""{vbCrLf}]"
    Dim FirstQuote As Integer = source.IndexOf("""")
    If FirstQuote > -1 And source.Length > FirstQuote Then
        Dim SecondQuote As Integer = source.IndexOf("""", FirstQuote + 1)
        If SecondQuote > FirstQuote Then
            Result = source.Substring(FirstQuote + 1, SecondQuote - FirstQuote - 1)
        End If
    End If

    If Result Is Nothing Then
        'Handle Invalid Format
    Else
        'Process Result
    End If
```

You would need to modify that so that you passed your source string, rather than defining it in the code.  If you wanted to extract multiple words from a single string in the same format, just set FirstQuote = SecondQuote + 1, check that doesn't exceed the length of the source string and loop through again.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume that you probably just need to **get the first occurance of a string** *(in this case "apple")* **within square-brackets using split** and so:

```vb
Dim AppleString As String = "This is an [Apple] or etc [...]"
console.WriteLine(AppleString.split("[")(1).split("]")(0).trim())
```

<sup>⚠️ This is not a solution for all purposes !!!</sup>

Comment: Nice option, although it will through an OutOfRangeException if string doesn't contain both an opening and a closing square bracket so best validate first unless certain of format.

Comment: *" if string doesn't contain an opening square bracket..."* **\***, Thanks, you got a point. Although I think that it is great enough for the *(assumed)* desired purpose, as it is.

Comment: Agreed - and yes, you're right, a missing closing bracket won't throw the error, it would return the entire string after the opening bracket. I like the use of Trim to remove the vbCrLfs too.